# How to distinguish mouse "click" and "drag"

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use `jQuery.click` to handle the mouse click event on Raphael graph, meanwhile, I need to handle mouse `drag` event, mouse drag consists of `mousedown`, `mouseup`and `mousemove` in Raphael.

It is difficult to distinguish `click` and `drag` because `click` also contain `mousedown` & `mouseup`, How can I distinguish mouse "click" & mouse "drag" then in Javascript?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

I think the difference is that there is a `mousemove` between `mousedown` and `mouseup` in a drag, but not in a click.

You can do something like this:

```js
const element = document.createElement('div')
element.textContent = 'test'
document.body.appendChild(element)

let moved = false
const downListener = () => {
  moved = false
}
const moveListener = () => {
  moved = true
}
const upListener = () => {
  if (moved) {
    console.log('moved')
  } else {
    console.log('not moved')
  }
}

// Attach listeners
element.addEventListener('mousedown', downListener)
element.addEventListener('mousemove', moveListener)
element.addEventListener('mouseup', upListener)

// Release memory
element.removeEventListener('mousedown', downListener)
element.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveListener)
element.removeEventListener('mouseup', upListener)
```

Comment: Just remember to require a minimum delta X or Y on mousemove to trigger a drag. Would be frustrating to try to click and get a drag operation instead due to a one tick mousemove

Comment: it can be just a mousemove if flag == 1 right? no neccessary drag.

Comment: @yeeen then there will be no `mouseup`

Comment: I don't think this works anymore in the lastest chrome:  32.0.1700.72
Mousemove fires whether you move mouse or not

Comment: This accepted answer code should include a minimum delta condition between XY mouse coordinates at `mousedown` and `mouseup` instead of listening to the `mousemove` event to set a flag. Moreover, it would fix the issue mentioned by @mrjrdnthms

Comment: I'm running Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) and I'm not experiencing the issues @mrjrdnthms is describing.

Comment: It has a little bug. If I move mouse over the `xxxx` element, `flag` get `1` and never turn to `0` , so never see the `click`.

Comment: @AmerllicA this is probably not a bug but expected behavior, however you could watch the mouseenter and mouseleave events if that's interesting to your use case

Comment: No need to use `mousedown`/`mouseup` events anymore, you can just use the native drag events - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: @Catalin it's still needed for custom interactions like panning a map / graph / image carousel. The drag events don't have x/y information; they're analogous to OS-level text / file drag-and-drop; i.e. for data transfer.

Comment: Using `#element::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` remove scroll and works perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 75):

All these solutions either break on tiny mouse movements, or are overcomplicated.

Here is a simple adaptable solution using two event listeners. Delta is the distance in pixels that you must move horizontally or vertically between the up and down events for the code to classify it as a drag rather than a click. This is because sometimes you will move the mouse or your finger a few pixels before lifting it.

```js
const delta = 6;
let startX;
let startY;

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  startX = event.pageX;
  startY = event.pageY;
});

element.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
  const diffX = Math.abs(event.pageX - startX);
  const diffY = Math.abs(event.pageY - startY);

  if (diffX < delta && diffY < delta) {
    // Click!
  }
});
```

Comment: By far the best answer!

Comment: Hi @andreyrd, may i know what `delta` is used for this? it is something to do with tap in mobile device?

Comment: @Haziq I think as people mentioned in comments of top solutions `delta` is used for "Would be frustrating to try to click and get a drag operation instead due to a one tick mousemove"

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation. Basically if your finger less than 6 pixels, it will still count as a click. If it moves 6 or more pixels, it will count as a drag.

Comment: Nice. Be aware that this doesn't serve properly in _some_ cases. **One example**: drag&dropping. Dragging something away but coming back with it because user changed his mind can have undesired click as result. In such a case, a threshold delta must be checked on `mousemove` as some answers here suggest.

Comment: This solution considers "moving around however far and long while holding button pressed and then releasing it right where you started from" as also a click.

Answer (score 57):

### Cleaner ES2015

```js
let drag = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => drag = false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => drag = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => console.log(drag ? 'drag' : 'click'));
```

Didn't experience any bugs, as others comment.

Comment: This suffers from clicks with tiny moves.

Comment: @AmirKeibi you could count the number of mousemoves (or even compute the distance between the two clicks but that would be overkill)

Comment: works without issues.

Answer (score 38):

In case you are already using jQuery:

```
var $body = $('body');
$body.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
  $body.on('mouseup mousemove', function handler(evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'mouseup') {
      // click
    } else {
      // drag
    }
    $body.off('mouseup mousemove', handler);
  });
});
```

Comment: Even if you move the mouse a tiny bit while clicking, this will say `drag`. An extra scope like other comments are saying may be needed here.

Comment: @ChiMo What I'm been using is storing mouse position from the first `evt` and comparing with the position of the second `evt`, so, for example: `if (evt.type === 'mouseup' || Math.abs(evt1.pageX - evt2.pageX) < 5 || Math.abs(evt1.pageY - evt2.pageY) < 5) { ...`.

Comment: I tried all other answers to this question, and this is the only one that worked when checking for `.on('mouseup mousemove touchend touchmove')`, and on top of that doesn't set position variables. Great solution!

Comment: Sometimes when I clicked on an element the "evt.type" return "mousemove" instead on mouseup. How can I resolve that issue?

Answer (score 18):

This should work well. Similar to the accepted answer (though using jQuery), but the `isDragging` flag is only reset if the new mouse position differs from that on `mousedown` event. Unlike the accepted answer, that works on recent versions of Chrome, where `mousemove` is fired regardless of whether mouse was moved or not.

```
var isDragging = false;
var startingPos = [];
$(".selector")
    .mousedown(function (evt) {
        isDragging = false;
        startingPos = [evt.pageX, evt.pageY];
    })
    .mousemove(function (evt) {
        if (!(evt.pageX === startingPos[0] && evt.pageY === startingPos[1])) {
            isDragging = true;
        }
    })
    .mouseup(function () {
        if (isDragging) {
            console.log("Drag");
        } else {
            console.log("Click");
        }
        isDragging = false;
        startingPos = [];
    });
```

You may also adjust the coordinate check in `mousemove` if you want to add a little bit of tolerance (i.e. treat tiny movements as clicks, not drags).

Answer (score 14):

#### If you feel like using [Rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs):

```js
var element = document;

Rx.Observable
  .merge(
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(element, 'mousedown').mapTo(0),
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(element, 'mousemove').mapTo(1)
  )
  .sample(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(element, 'mouseup'))
  .subscribe(flag => {
      console.clear();
      console.log(flag ? "drag" : "click");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.1/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

This is a direct clone of what @wong2 did in his answer, but converted to RxJs.

Also interesting use of [`sample`](http://rxmarbles.com/#sample). The `sample` operator will take the latest value from the source (the `merge` of `mousedown` and `mousemove`) and emit it when the inner observable (`mouseup`) emits.

Comment: I write all my code with observables so that my boss can't hire someone else to replace me.

Answer (score 11):

As mrjrdnthms points out in his comment on the accepted answer, this no longer works on Chrome (it always fires the mousemove), I've adapted Gustavo's answer (since I'm using jQuery) to address the Chrome behavior.

```
var currentPos = [];

$(document).on('mousedown', function (evt) {

   currentPos = [evt.pageX, evt.pageY]

  $(document).on('mousemove', function handler(evt) {

    currentPos=[evt.pageX, evt.pageY];
    $(document).off('mousemove', handler);

  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function handler(evt) {

    if([evt.pageX, evt.pageY].equals(currentPos))
      console.log("Click")
    else
      console.log("Drag")

    $(document).off('mouseup', handler);

  });

});
```

The `Array.prototype.equals` function comes from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/187126)

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I got an error from the `[evt.pageX, evt.pageY].equals()` command.  I replaced that with `(evt.pageX === currentPos[0] && evt.pageY===currentPos[1])`, and all was good. :)

Comment: The `equals` code needs to be added from the link at the bottom of my post

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the logic. Why do you update `currentPos` on `mousemove`?  Doesn't this mean that you would treat some drags as clicks?

Comment: a click that started, moved the mouse and released is a drag

Comment: This doesn't fire if you `"mouseup"` while still moving the mouse.

Comment: FYI: Instead of `$(document).on('mousemove', function() { ... $(document).off('mousemove'); });` etc, you can just use `$document.one('mousemove'...` which only listens once, then turns itself off.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery with a 5 pixel x/y theshold to detect the drag:

```
var dragging = false;
$("body").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  var x = e.screenX;
  var y = e.screenY;
  dragging = false;
  $("body").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (Math.abs(x - e.screenX) > 5 || Math.abs(y - e.screenY) > 5) {
      dragging = true;
    }
  });
});
$("body").on("mouseup", function(e) {
  $("body").off("mousemove");
  console.log(dragging ? "drag" : "click");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", lift);
  var didDrag = false;
  function drag() {
    //when the person drags their mouse while holding the mouse button down
    didDrag = true;
    div.innerHTML = "drag"
  }
  function lift() {
    //when the person lifts mouse
    if (!didDrag) {
      //if the person didn't drag
      div.innerHTML = "click";
    } else div.innerHTML = "drag";
    //delete event listeners so that it doesn't keep saying drag
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag)
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#div {
  /* calculating -5px for each side of border in case border-box doesn't work */
  width: calc(100vw - 10px);
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
  border: 5px solid orange;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div">Click me or drag me.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took your approach and made a [React version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64766667/2891356) for anyone interested.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem recently with a tree list where the user can either click on the item or drag it, made this small `Pointer` class and put it in my `utils.js`

```js
function Pointer(threshold = 10) {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  return {
    start(e) {
     x = e.clientX;
     y = e.clientY;
    },

    isClick(e) {
      const deltaX = Math.abs(e.clientX - x);
      const deltaY = Math.abs(e.clientY - y);
      return deltaX < threshold && deltaY < threshold;
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see it at work:

```js
function Pointer(threshold = 10) {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;

  return {
    start(e) {
     x = e.clientX;
     y = e.clientY;
    },

    isClick(e) {
      const deltaX = Math.abs(e.clientX - x);
      const deltaY = Math.abs(e.clientY - y);
      return deltaX < threshold && deltaY < threshold;
    }
  }
}

const pointer = new Pointer();

window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => pointer.start(e))
//window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => pointer.last(e))
window.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  const operation = pointer.isClick(e) 
    ? "Click"
    : "Drag"
  console.log(operation)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

**It's really this simple**

```
var dragged = false
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () { dragged = false })
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function () { dragged = true })
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        if (dragged == true) { return }
        console.log("CLICK!! ")
})
```

You honestly **do not want to add a threshold** allowing a small movement. The above is the correct, normal, feel of clicking on all desktop interfaces.

Just try it.

You can easily [add an event](https://javascript.info/dispatch-events) if you like.

Answer (score 3):

If just to filter out the drag case, do it like this:

```
var moved = false;
$(selector)
  .mousedown(function() {moved = false;})
  .mousemove(function() {moved = true;})
  .mouseup(function(event) {
    if (!moved) {
        // clicked without moving mouse
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Another solution for class based vanilla JS using a distance threshold**

```
private initDetectDrag(element) {
    let clickOrigin = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    const dragDistanceThreshhold = 20;

    element.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
        this.isDragged = false
        clickOrigin = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    });
    element.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(clickOrigin.y - event.clientY, 2) + Math.pow(clickOrigin.x - event.clientX, 2)) > dragDistanceThreshhold) {
            this.isDragged = true
        }
    });
}
```

Add inside the class (SOMESLIDER_ELEMENT can also be *document* to be global):

```
private isDragged: boolean;
constructor() {
    this.initDetectDrag(SOMESLIDER_ELEMENT);
    this.doSomeSlideStuff(SOMESLIDER_ELEMENT);
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (!this.sliderIsDragged) {
            console.log('was clicked');
        } else {
            console.log('was dragged, ignore click or handle this');
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pure JS with DeltaX and DeltaY

This DeltaX and DeltaY as suggested by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042202/how-to-distinguish-mouse-click-and-drag#comment13767593_6042235) in the accepted answer to avoid the frustrating experience when trying to click and get a drag operation instead due to a one tick mousemove.

```
    deltaX = deltaY = 2;//px
    var element = document.getElementById('divID');
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
        if (typeof InitPageX == 'undefined' && typeof InitPageY == 'undefined') {
            InitPageX = e.pageX;
            InitPageY = e.pageY;
        }

    }, false);
    element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        if (typeof InitPageX !== 'undefined' && typeof InitPageY !== 'undefined') {
            diffX = e.pageX - InitPageX;
            diffY = e.pageY - InitPageY;
            if (    (diffX > deltaX) || (diffX < -deltaX)
                    || 
                    (diffY > deltaY) || (diffY < -deltaY)   
                    ) {
                console.log("dragging");//dragging event or function goes here.
            }
            else {
                console.log("click");//click event or moving back in delta goes here.
            }
        }
    }, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
        delete InitPageX;
        delete InitPageY;
    }, false);

   element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("click");
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a public action on an OSM map (position a marker on click) the question was: 1) how to determine the duration of mouse down->up (you can't imagine creating a new marker for each click) and 2) did the mouse move during down->up (i.e user is dragging the map).

```
const map = document.getElementById('map');

map.addEventListener("mousedown", position); 
map.addEventListener("mouseup", calculate);

let posX, posY, endX, endY, t1, t2, action;

function position(e) {

  posX = e.clientX;
  posY = e.clientY;
  t1 = Date.now();

}

function calculate(e) {

  endX = e.clientX;
  endY = e.clientY;
  t2 = (Date.now()-t1)/1000;
  action = 'inactive';

  if( t2 > 0.5 && t2 < 1.5) { // Fixing duration of mouse down->up

      if( Math.abs( posX-endX ) < 5 && Math.abs( posY-endY ) < 5 ) { // 5px error on mouse pos while clicking
         action = 'active';
         // --------> Do something
      }
  }
  console.log('Down = '+posX + ', ' + posY+'\nUp = '+endX + ', ' + endY+ '\nAction = '+ action);    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63973098/2891356) answer, I did this in my React component:

```
export default React.memo(() => {
    const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseMove);

        return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseMove);
    }, []);

    const handleMouseMove = React.useCallback(() => {
        const drag = (e) => {
            console.log('mouse is moving');
        };

        const lift = (e) => {
            console.log('mouse move ended');
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this);
        };

        window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', lift);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }} ref={containerRef} />
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want check the click or drag behavior of a specific element you can do this without having to listen to the body.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let click;
  
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1
  });
  
  // prevent clicks when sliding
  $('.btn')
    .on('mousemove', function(){
      click = false;
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(){
      click = true;
    });
    
  // change mouseup listener to '.content' to listen to a wider area. (mouse drag release could happen out of the '.btn' which we have not listent to). Note that the click will trigger if '.btn' mousedown event is triggered above
  $('.btn').on('mouseup', function(){
    if(click){
      $('.result').text('clicked');
    } else {
      $('.result').text('dragged');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.slider, .result{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.slider{
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 30px;
}
.btn{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  background: #c66;
}
.result{
  height: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="btn" draggable="true">click me without moving the mouse</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="btn" draggable="true">click me without moving the mouse</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from @Przemek 's answer,

```js
function listenClickOnly(element, callback, threshold=10) {
  let drag = 0;
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => drag = 0);
  element.addEventListener('mousemove', () => drag++);
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (drag<threshold) callback(e);
  });
}

listenClickOnly(
  document,
  () => console.log('click'),
  10
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following coding is to detect the movement of `mouseup` and `mousedown`.

> It shall work for most of the cases. It also depends
> on how you treat `mouseevent` as Click.
>
> In JavaScript, the detection is very simple. It does not concern how
> long you press or movement between the mousedown and mouseup.
> `Event.detail` would not reset to 1 when your mouse is moved between
> the `mousedown` and `mouseup`.
>
> If you need to differentiate the click and long press, you need to
> check the difference in `event.timeStamp` too.

```js
// ==== add the code at the begining of your coding ====
let clickStatus = 0;
(() => {
    let screenX, screenY;
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => ({screenX, screenY} = event), true); 
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => (clickStatus = Math.abs(event.screenX - screenX) + Math.abs(event.screenY - screenY) < 3), true);
})();
// ==== add the code at the begining of your coding ====

$("#draggable").click(function(event) {
    if (clickStatus) {
        console.log(`click event is valid, click count: ${event.detail}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`click event is invalid`)
    }

})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- coding example from https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ -->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy,

```js
el = document.getElementById("your_id");
var isDown = false;
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    isDown = true;
});
el.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    isDown = false;
});
el.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
    if (isDown) {
        // your code goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a global variable `isDragging` which can be tested at any time to see if the mouse is currently in drag mode, or simply being moved around without any button being clicked.

```html
let isDragging = false;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if(event.buttons > 0) {
        isDragging = true;
    } else {
        isDragging = false;
    }
});
```