# If I hold down the left or right mouse button, mouseenter doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseenter

I am making a game where you touch certain blocks with the mouse to score points, and others lose you the game. My friend found a bug where if you hold down the left or right mouse button, the computer will not detect either mouseenter events. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: thats because that combination is reserved for Drag and Drop operations

Comment: When you click and move, that's considered a drag. This answer will probably be helpful for what you're trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042202/how-to-distinguish-mouse-click-and-drag

Comment: @ruedamanuel that wont help because in WinForms DragOver and DragEnter are called as a result of a DoDragDrop which the OP probably doesnt not want to initiate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, when a control gets a MouseDown event from the user pressing a mouse button, it "captures" the mouse input from that moment until the mouse button is released.  This is used to provide the MouseUp event even if the mouse moved away from the control.

You would have to override that but there is a side-effect:

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                               Handles Panel1.MouseDown
  Panel1.Capture = False
End Sub
```

Now you have no guarantee the MouseUp event will fire unless the mouse is directly over the control.