# Multi select within an optgroup - the event's target is the optgroup

Tags: jquery, html, optgroup

I have a `select` with some `optgroup`s.

```
<select multiple style="height: 500px; width: 300px">
  <optgroup label="Colours">
    <option value="G">Green</option>
    <option value="B">Blue</option>
    <option value="Y">Yellow</option>
    <option value="W">White</option>
    <option value="P">Pink</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Numbers">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to be able to click the `optgroup` and select all the child `options`. I found that when clicking an individual `option`, the event still fired, so by testing the `e.target` I can make sure the target is the `optgroup` and only select the children then.

```
$(document).on("click", "optgroup", function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);

  console.log(target);

  if (target.is("optgroup")) { 
    target.find("option").prop("selected", true);
  }
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0z61fzs4/

So far, so good.

However try and multi-select by doing a click-and-drag - on the Fiddle below just drag from "One" down to "Three". The event target in this instance ends up being the `optgroup` itself and not the `option`, so by selecting a couple of options in this manner, you end up with selecting everything in the optgroup.

This behaviour only occurs with a click-and-drag type selection. It does not occur with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click multiple selection.

Further, it does not occur if you "cross a boundary". For example in the fiddle attached, if you start at "White" and click-drag down to "Three" then you are multi-selecting from two different groups. In this instance the target ends up as the `option` and the behaviour works as expected.

How can I allow the click-drag type behaviour I want, to select multiple `options` within a single `optgroup` without the JS firing and selecting them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your click event to a mouseup event and see if that works as you expect.

```
$(document).on("mouseup", "optgroup", function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);

  if (target.is("optgroup")) { 
    target.find("option").prop("selected", true);
  };
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0z61fzs4/2/

Comment: @Abhitalks This answer worked great for me without `stopPropagation()`. Why would I need to use that?

Comment: @bgs264: Never mind. My main point was to ensure that the Op writes a complete answer instead of a one liner which was at risk of deletion.

Comment: @Abhitalks Yeah cheers mate, I don't often respond on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Abhitalks I don't understand. I have read several times the "Guidance for answers" (here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Nothing said that one lines were at risk of deletion, nothing says to provide code samples. Upon what grounds do you base your comments? I thought the answer was fine - "replace click to mouseup" - it was concise and worked. I know how to do that, I don't need a full sample showing one event replaced to another?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at mousedown/mousemove combinations? See this thread for more info: [How to distinguish mouse "click" and "drag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042202/how-to-distinguish-mouse-click-and-drag)