# How to differentiate between a click and a drag using jQuery, but get only one click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I am using the following answer to solve my problem, however, it always registers either two clicks or two drags instead of just one. What could be the problem for that? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31080629/5632752
The div that I am using the .draggable() function on looks like this:

```
<div id="draggable"><div>Hello World</div></div>
```

Comment: Did you call the `.on("mousedown")` init twice?   Can you recreate the issue either here in a snippet or on something like jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you use the answer you linked to or the accepted answer on the question?

Comment: I used the answer that I linked to, however I think it was not working correctly because I have two `$(document).ready()` functions which both did different things, so it registered two clicks. I put the code under a `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML page and now it works just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the code for differentiation under `$(document).ready()` and that, for some reason, registered two clicks instead of one. I added the code under a `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML page and now it works just as it should.